# No results returned by MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am testing an application which connects to database and retrieve results. It uses PHP, and Joomla framework.
The thing is that if I put a query as

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__coupon_member_details";
$this->_db->setQuery($query);        
$result = $this->_db->query();
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($number == 0 ){
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("no data returned by db");
}else{
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($number);
}
```

The above code gives message "no data returned by db" except the fact that the table contains a lot of data (200+ rows).

If I put invalid table name as `#__coupon_member_details123`, then it produces an error saying "Table does not exist".

I fail to understand what is wrong ?

Comment: please stop usingg deprecated `mysql_*` . use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. also what `var_dump($number);` outputs?

Comment: the code was written 2 years back, so I cannot change it to new extension as of now. 

`var_dump($number); ` prints nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joomla you have to use correct Joomla API which goes like this. `mysql_num_rows` equivalent in Joomla is `getNumRows`

```
$query = $this->_db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__coupon_member_details";
$this->_db->setQuery($query);
$result = $this->_db->query();
$numRows = $this->_db->getNumRows();
if($numRows == 0 ){
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("no data returned by db");
}else{
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($number);
}
```

Comment: So for other queries like `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`, I have to use Joomla specific queries ?

Comment: @sanA You can use $this->_db->loadAssocList(); For full details you can check this page https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__coupon_member_details";
$this->_db->setQuery($query);
$arrResult = $this->_db->loadAssocList();
$intCountResults = count($arrResult);
```

The above query will return the data in `$arrResult`, and the number of results in `$intCountResults`.

If you only want the number, then I suggest you change the above to:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `totalcount` FROM #__coupon_member_details";
$this->_db->setQuery($query);
$intCountResults = $this->_db->loadResult();
```

This is better and is scalable. Even better you could do something like SELECT `count(id)` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` (if you have an `id` field).